# Query not returning expected results group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I am going a little crazy here. I was wondering if may be someone could help me understand why this query is not returning expected results

```
SELECT
  last_name,
  first_name,
  DATE_FORMAT((tm_date), '%Y-%m-%d') AS dates,
  SUM(tm_hours) total
FROM timecard
LEFT JOIN teachers i
  ON i.ds_id = timecard.ds_id
WHERE tm_notes != 'Lunch Break'
AND tm_date BETWEEN '2018-04-16' AND '2018-04-30'
AND timecard.ds_id = '4'
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(tm_date), '/', WEEK(tm_date)),
         timecard.ds_id
ORDER BY last_name ASC, dates ASC
```

This query will return the first record as if the week started on 2018-04-20 but it should be 2018-04-16. When I run this query for other users timecard.ds_id the query always returns 2018-04-16 as the first record I don't understand why with this particular user its showing 2018-04-20.

this are the results

[image: results]

this is sample data

[image: sample data]

Thank you

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  And if you can simplify the query, that is also helpful.

Comment: Use proper `GROUP BY`.  The columns `first_name` and `last_name` is not even in group by.

Comment: The query relies on a MySQL-specific, non-standard extension to `GROUP BY`; the values returned for non-aggregates expressions in the SELECT list which are not in the GROUP BY (or functionally dependent on expressions in the GROUP BY) are *indeterminate*. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When selecting a column not included your group by clause and not fed to an aggregate function, MySQL picks an arbitrary `tm_date` row from the grouped rows. (This is a setting; you can change it and MySQL will throw an exception)

You have to tell MySQL what you want. I think `MIN` works here.

```
DATE_FORMAT(MIN(tm_date), '%Y-%m-%d') AS dates,
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I just learned something new! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Here's the MySQL documentation for what Terminus specifies. It's worth reading. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

> If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you want. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Result set sorting occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which value within each group the server chooses. Disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is useful primarily when you know that, due to some property of the data, all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group.

Comment: Thanks, my Google-fu is weak today.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's grouping by week, you may not always get the result you're looking for. If you want the earliest result, then use `MIN`

```
DATE_FORMAT(MIN(tm_date), '%Y-%m-%d') AS dates,
```